# $N$-Body Solar System Simulator - Why are there inaccuracies in the $x$ plane but not the others?

Tags: orbital-motion, computational-physics, simulations, solar-system, software

I have written a basic $N$-Body simulator that simulates the motion of the planets in the solar system.

The system reads the positions and velocities of the planets at a given time, measures the time for one full orbit of each planet and then compares the accuracy of the simulation against a highly accurate model.

I have analysed the data in the $x$, $y$ and $z$ planes. Interestingly, the simulation is highly accurate in the $y$ and $z$ planes but about 10x less accurate in the $x$ plane. See attached graph.

Any idea why this is? I am thinking it is perhaps because the angular momentum from planets spinning on their axis has some effect on their orbit in the x plane? Or perhaps the effect of dark matter?

[image]

Here is the bit of the code that does the 'simulating'.

```
for nk = 2:length(LY)
t = 0;
dt = LY(nk)/num_it; 
G = 6.67e-11;
t_finish = LY(nk); %One orbital period for selected planet                      
N_t = round(t_finish/dt);
N = length(p); %find number of objects in simulation
%view in center of mass frame
v = v - mean((m*[1 1 1]).*v)/mean(m);
%find accelleration
a = a_v(p, m, G, sft);
%find starting energy
[KE,PE] = E(v,p,G,m);
%Main Simulation
for n = 1:N_t
    
    %'kick drift kick' second order technique is used here. This teqnique is
    %used as it preserves energy fairly efficiently. Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leapfrog_integration
    
    %first 1/2 kick
    v = v + a*dt/2;
    
    %drift
    p = p + v*dt;
    
    %new accellerations
    a = a_v(p,m,G,sft);
    
    %second 1/2 kick
    v = v + a*dt/2;
    
    %new time
    t = t + dt;
end
psave(nk,:) = p(nk,:);
vsave(nk,:) = v(nk,:);
end
```

Comment: What is the x-axis in your model?

Comment: Apologies for not being clearer. The x axis just represents each planet, in order from nearest to furthest from the sun. So 2 is Mercury, 3 Earth, 4 Mars, etc.

I have also tried plotting orbital period and mass on the x axis, but neither provide any kind of pattern with regards to when/where the x descrepencies are more likely to occur.

Comment: Sorry I meant the x-plane. Is it the plane containing the orbits?

Comment: The simulation starts by reading the x y and z co-ordinates for each planet with the sun being at 0,0,0. After the simulation is run, each simulated co ordinate is divided by the expected co ordinate to give a ratio, which is plotted on the graph.

For example the red point on the plot for pluto would be x_pluto_simulated / x_pluto_model

Comment: a model is a simulation too, so you are comparing two models. You have to compare with real measured numbers to get real discrepancies, no? If the "model" describes accurately  the solar system, there can be no questions about dark matter , imo. there must be something not take into account in your simulation.

Comment: I agree that I am missing something! I am trying to figure out what I am missing so I can add it into the simulation. I am wondering if it could be dark matter too - although I thought perhaps the descrepancy I have encountered is too large for dark matter to be responsible. That said, I don't know much about dark matter.

I am also running on the assumption that the model I am using (DE432t), is considerably more accurate than mine.

Comment: One thing you are missing is that a simple forward simulation accumulates errors quickly.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about debugging code and algorithms.

Comment: Why would errors accumulate more in x than the other co ordinates though Jon? The code that applies to each co ordinate is the same. The orbit is also measured over one full oscillation so any error in x should at least be duplicated in y.

Answer (score 1):

Dark matter has a negligible effect on planetary dynamics - otherwise we would have discovered it much sooner than we did.

The rotational angular momentum of a planet as it rotates about its axis is negligible compared to its orbital angular momentum. The radius of the Earth's orbit is around $25000$ times the Earth's own radius, and its orbital angular speed is only $\frac 1 {365}$ of its rotational angular speed, so its orbital angular momentum $mr^2\omega$ is around $1700$ times its rotational angular momentum.

A much more likely explanation is an error in your code. The orbits of most planets are close to circles and lie in approximately the same plane, so we would expect any differences between one model and another to have more or less the same distributions for $x$ and $y$ co-ordinates (assuming the $xy$ plane is close to the plane of the ecliptic). The fact that your errors select the $x$ axis suggests a coding error somewhere.

Comment: These my guesses on Dark Matter and rotational angular momentum too, thanks a lot for clarifying.

I am struggling to see how an error in my code could be causing this, as the same functions are applied to the x, y and z co ordinates. So surely any error would be replicated across all? Of course it is possible/likely that I am mis understanding something!

Is it possible that the error is caused as I have not included some other significant masses in the solar system, such as dwarf planets, moons, etc? The discrepancy occurs largest for Neptune, which has some very large moons, for example